# タプル分解の利点が知りたい

Tags: c#

タプル式なのですが、`//ここです`のコードの部分は何が利点なのでしょうか？
タプル型を返す？関数の`GetMember(string s, int n){}`の利点は理解できますが
`t1`の部分の利点が知りたいです。

```
class sample
{ 
    static void Main()
    {
        (string, int) GetMember(string s, int n)
        {
            string a = s;
            int b = n;
            return (a, b);
        }
        var (aa, x) = GetMember("bbb", 4);

        (string s1, int n1) t1 = ("qqq", 2);  //ここです。
        var (a2, x2) = GetMember(t1.s1, t1.n1);

        (int a, int b) t2 = (3, 3);

        Console.WriteLine(a2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 関数のGetMember(string s, int n){}の利点は理解できますが

おそらく多値戻り値の利点は理解されていて、なぜt1の行の代入でタプルを使っているかって事ですよね？この認識で話を進めますが、おそらくGetMemberの引数に渡すパラメータはt1と言う名前にしたかったんじゃないでしょうか？GetMemberの引数をt1とすれば他では使われる必要がないからとかですかね？作った人に聞いてみるのが早いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

メソッドの引数は複数指定できるように、戻り値も複数指定したい場合があり、それを実現するのが多値であり、C#におけるその実装がタプルです。
タプルはあくまで多値を表すための便宜的な構造でしかなく、それ自体に意味を持たせる目的はありません。ですので、タプルのまま扱うのではなく、早々に分解し個別の値として扱うことに意義があります。タプル分解構文が導入された理由もそこにあります。[タプルとその他の型の分解](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct)も参照してください。

なお、C#がよく参考にする[F#言語](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/)を見るといろいろな機能を知ることができます。F#には[パターンマッチ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching)という機能があり、これがタプル分解の元ネタとなっています。F#の場合、タプルだけでなく配列やリスト・レコードなど多くの型を分解でき、なおかつ再帰的にどこまででも分解することができます。対するC#のタプル分解は１階層のみのため、あまり存在意義を発揮できていないかもしれませんが、今後のバージョンで強化されるという話もあります。

Comment: 「C#のタプル分解は１階層のみ」の部分を詳しく教えて頂けませんでしょうか？　C#でもネストしたタプルの分解は`var (a, (b, c)) = x`みたくできると思うのですが……。

Answer (score 1):

なんか見るからに説明のための説明として「こんなことができますよ」という例が挙げてあるだけのように見えます。そこに「利点」を探しても仕方ないのでは？

`tuple` も結局のところ「複数個の値をひとつにまとめて扱う」という点では `class` や `struct` と同じ機能なわけです。 `class` の場合、事前に＝「使う場所とは離れた場所」で定義が必要で、再利用が可能なわけです。 `tuple` の場合、今ここでしか必要のない値のセットを ad hoc （やっつけ）に、使う場所で定義することができて、なおかつ再利用しづらい＝元作者による「他のところで再利用すんなゴラァ」の意思表明と読むことができます。単純なものを使い捨てるには `tuple` のほうが手早いっすね。